# "Undefined index" when trying to insert JSON file into SQL in PHP

Tags: json

im trying to insert multiple JSON files into a database(about 20-30 in total, im using 2 for now to test). All the files will have the same format. I inserted the files into an HTML table previously so i used the same loop so my script inserts any JSON file found in the directory into the database. I am however getting some errors 1) "Undefined index : Comments" and 2) Table 'serverd.serverd' doesn't exist. Any guidance would be appreciated. I have moved my brackets around but no luck.

```
'<?php
$connect =mysqli_connect("reservation","-----","-----","serverD") or 
die("could not connect");

$dir = "/Users/-----/Desktop/reserve/sql";

if (is_dir($dir)) {

if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
  foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($filename);
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);   

    $Manufacturer = $data['Comments']['Manufacturer'];
    $Model = $data['Comments']['Model'];
    $BIOSFamily = $data['Comments']['BIOSFamily'];
    $BIOSDATE = $data['Comments']['BIOSDate'];
    $SerialNumber = $data['Comments']['SerialNumber'];

$sql= " INSERT INTO serverD(Manufacturer, Model, BIOSFamily, BIOSDate, SerialNumber)
          VALUES('$Manufacturer' , '$Model'  , '$BIOSFamily' ,  '$BIOSDate' ,  '$SerialNumber')";

$query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
}
}
}
?>'
```

Comment: "Table 'serverd.serverd' doesn't exist" => changing brackets around will never solve this. You need to create the table with this name or change your code to use the correct name. "Undefined index : Comments"  => your `$data` structure has no `Comments` part. So you need to test for it, or change your structure in JSON file or change the code loading it.

Comment: okay so i fixed the errors. I get no errors now but, when i insert into my sql table the variable is inserted ie, under Manufacturer i get $Manufacturer, Model i get $Model etc so it seems my variable declarations is incorrect. My varialble declarations are the same as above i just put my "foreach($testing as $data) right before the variables,